# Copy rows with specific text in a column VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am very new to VBA and all coding so I'm not very good at even the basics yet.

I have a worksheet in excel with about a dozen different business' Balance Sheets. I need to copy all of the the rows in a specific range based on the Asset name in column D. The specific range I need to copy is in between "Securities" and "Derivatives."

I successfully copied all the lines of data in between the first set of "Securities" and "Derivatives" but my For Loop keeps copying the same first range when I need it to move to the next set of "Securities" and "Derivatives" Data.

I have tried and thought maybe adding a variable to my rngA might work? Any help is appreciated.

```
'''
    
Sub ChartReference2()
    Dim findrow As Long

    Dim findrow2 As Long
    Dim rngA As Range
    
    
    For Each cell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BS growth").Range("A:A")
        If cell.Value = "Asset" Then
            Worksheets("BS growth").Activate
            findrow = Range("D:D").Find("Securities", Range("D3")).Row
            findrow2 = Range("D:D").Find("Derivatives", Range("D" & findrow)).Row
            Range("D" & findrow & ":D" & findrow2, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
            Selection.Copy
    
    End If
    Next cell
    
    
    End Sub

'''
```

Comment: Let's say `Asset` is first found in `A5`, and the next is found in `A15`. 1.) Please share the exact range of where to find the `SecDer` combination (e.g. `D6:D14` or `D5:D14` or ...). 2.) Can there be more than one `SecDer` combination per `Asset`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this - comments in-line

```vb
Sub ChartReference2()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, assetRow, f1 As Range, f2 As Range
    
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BS growth")
    
    assetRow = Application.Match("Asset", ws.Columns("A"), 0)
    If Not IsError(assetRow) Then 'matched a cell in Col A?
        With ws.Columns("D")
            Set f1 = .Find("Securities", lookat:=xlWhole, after:=.Cells(assetRow - 1), _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext)
            If Not f1 Is Nothing Then      'found the value?
                Set f2 = .Find("Derivatives", lookat:=xlWhole, after:=f1, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext)
                If Not f2 Is Nothing Then  'found the value?
                    ws.Range(f1, f2).Copy  'copy range
                End If
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```